# SQL Replace string in path

Tags: sql

How would I replace everything before "Test" with a blank? The amount of subfolders in front of "Test" may vary.

C:\aaa\bbb\test\ccc\ddd

I would like it to be:

test\ccc\ddd

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution in MSSQL, if you're using another RDMBS I'm sure they have equivalent functions for PATINDEX/SUBSTRING.

```
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@Find VARCHAR(128)

SET @Path = 'C:\aaa\bbb\test\ccc\ddd'
SET @Find = 'Test\'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Path,PATINDEX('%'+@Find+'%',@Path),LEN(@Path))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8576

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the string Text in your String, and get a substring from there to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work in any SQL - you may add syntatic fixes if required. In Oracle it would be SUBSTR/INSTR for example.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str, start_pos) final_str
FROM
(
SELECT 'C:\aaa\bbb\test\ccc\ddd' as str 
     , INSTR('C:\aaa\bbb\test\ccc\ddd', 'test', 1) as start_pos
  FROM dual
)
/

SQL>

FINAL_STR
-------------
test\ccc\ddd
```